# How to make changes to branches in Git

Tags: git

I'm sure Git experts will find this question a noob... I am very new to Git and just learnt about creating branches. I did the following:

1. I created a branch say "branch1" on remote host (GitHub).
2. now I ran `git pull`-d branch1 to my local repository.
3. I ran `git checkout branch1`.
4. I opened my working folder and edited the README.md file in a text editor.

Now, running `git status` on *master*, and *branch1*, both show the edited README.md as *Modified*, while I edited the file only for `branch1`.
Do I need to have a different working directory for every branch to make changes only to a specific branch?

Comment: No. You were perfectly right. When you change branches and have uncomitted changes (like your README), then the changes _move_ from branch to branch as you switch branches until you commit them.

Comment: The file is changed in your working directory.  Those changes remain in your working directory until you commit them.

Comment: but when i changed to master branch and re-opened the file, I found that the text was same as I left when I was in `branch1` branch. My problem is If I want to work in two different branches simultaneously how can I achieve it?

Comment: Yes, that's expected behaviour. While on `branch1` you should have told Git _"Hey Git, I changed my file. Please record this change for `branch1`"_ (That's the `git add` and `git commit`). When you simply change branches, Git thinks _"Uhh, he made changes but didn't yet tell me to record them, so I'll keep them. Perhaps they're important."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to ignore the term 'working directory' for a moment, because I believe it is confusing you. You don't need to change directories to view different branches.

1. check out the branch you want to use
2. make the change you want to make
3. run `git add .` to "stage" the changes. That is to say you want to commit them. Run `git status` to before and after this to see the difference
4. run `git commit -m "some commit message"` to commit your changes
5. check out some other branch, and you will see that the changes you made are only in the branch where you made the commit.

The working directory is just which is under the control of Git. It's not something you need to be actively thinking about.

I hope this helps clear some of that up.

Answer (score 0):

The file is changed in your working directory. Those changes remain in your working directory until you commit them.

The way Git does it, you can fix things as you encounter them and distribute the changes among multiple commits on different branches when it's convenient.  This turns out to be a surprisingly handy facility. It's not confusing; it's novel. Yeah, that's it, "novel" :-).  All kidding aside, I think you'll grow accustomed to having it.  Look at the `--patch` option on add and reset and checkout, and the `--interactive` option on rebase.

Git's about constructing and publishing a polished, professionally-edited history.  If you regard the history you're constructing with your `git commit`s as a first draft, a huge number of Git's tools will start to make a whole lot of sense—and your work will get some combination of easier, faster, and better.

Comment: I found your answer useful, don't see a reason to downvote it.

Comment: atleast I can add one vote to this. I hate such opinionated voting.

Comment: The OP asked why his uncomitted changes move between branches and this answer proposes re-writing history.

Comment: @PerlDog, To define a downvote, take your mouse over the downvote and see what stackoverflow says, Downvote ONLY if this answer is not useful.

Comment: @RameshPareek That's exactly what I did. **I** didn't find it useful for that particular problem. And that _Git's about [...] polishing history_ is really new to me. But you're free to upvote.

Comment: History rewriting is why git's winning.  You publish histories.  The notion that published professional work shouldn't be professionally edited, or that you shouldn't use the tools at hand to do that editing, is ... confusing.

Comment: to some extent I agree to your point, and that's why I didn't accept his answer, but this definitely adds something useful to this post. the lines `you can fix things as you encounter them and distribute the changes among multiple commits on different branches when it's convenient.` left me amazed how he guessed that I was hesitating while committing a change.... and the lines  ' a huge number of git's tools will start to make a whole lot of sense -- and your work will get some combination of easier, faster, and better.'... really motivates me to learn new things.

Comment: @jthill You are right. I myself do rewrite history very frequently (before pushing!) and really enjoy it. I just thought it doesn't help when someone asks why uncomitted changes move around between branches. As I currently read, it helped and inspired Ramesh and that's what we are all here for, right? :-)

Comment: @PerlDog That (re the we're all here to help) is what I think too. I tend to write my answers to address the underlying situation, especially when someone else has already answered the question as asked. OP: thanks for your comment, it's really gratifying to know when I saw what I thought I saw.

Comment: Maybe I've overlooked something you have foreseen and/or underestimated the OP's skills and his thirst for knowledge. Given that your answer has three paragraphs, two of which I think _are_ helpful, so what is my choice? ;-)